# Double tap event in owl carousel

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-events, owl-carousel

As a Javscript beginner I'm trying to fetch a double tap event in owl carousel:

In `onDragEnd` function:

```
var lastTouch = $(this).data('lastTouch') || now + 1;
var timeDelta = now - lastTouch;
if (timeDelta < 300 && 0 < timeDelta) {
    $(this).data('lastTouch',null);
    //do scaling
}else{
    $(this).data('lastTouch',now);
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is some kind of double tap zoom (via `transform:scale`?). Has someone already tried to achieve a similar function? I haven't found anything.

Comment: I'm not sure but it seems that your calculation of the delta is wrong. You have to declare `lastTouch` outside your handler. Also your question is too vague. Better ask what specific problem you have and not for a whole solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I thought `$(this).data('lastTouch')` would do the trick. And you are right, I should improve my js skills first and ask later. :-)

Comment: Can you advice a good reading for js/jquery programming? I do have a programming background so I don't need js for dummies and no explanation of loops and conditions. It's hard at first to get used to all these shorthands, coding/naming conventions etc.

Comment: Sorry, you are right with `data` I haven't seen this! Well maybe you should use the debugger or `console.log` to see if all lines work as you expect it. After that you might be able to improve your question. Try to add the surrounding lines too. One thing might be `now` it's not defined anywhere? For a book I would recommend "JavaScript: The Good Parts" from  Douglas Crockford.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a solution for you but without using an event from Owl Carousel 2:

```
$(function() {
  var last = null;
  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    center      : true,
    margin      : 10,
    loop        : true,
    autoWidth   : true, 
    items       : 3
  }).on('touchend', function(e) {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    last = last || now;
    if (now - last < 300 && now - last > 0) {
      last = null;
      console.log('double tap');
    } else if (last !== now) {
      last = null;
    }
  });
});
```

Here is a JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/tebazugi/1/edit.

Comment: Thank you, witrin! With your help and a small addition (I have to check if it is the same event) it is working.